# Free Program To Convert 16:9 (1920x1080) to 4:3 (1920x1440)

Tags: gratis, video

Hello im looking for a free piece of software that can convert between 16:9 and 4:3. I have already tried freemake video converter but that has a watermark, I also tried FFmpeg but wasn't a fan of the cmd interface.

Comment: Welcome! What operating system(s)?

Comment: We can't help us if you don't tell us what OS. Please edit your question, then ask us to reopen. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your platform includes Windows or Linux, you may find the program at the right cost in [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/), a free non-linear video editor.

I've used the software on both Windows and Linux and find the Linux version to be a bit more stable, but it's still a capable program in Windows. The most recent version appears to have addressed some of the instabilities, but save your work often.

To address your primary question, I used Google to search for "kdenlive convert 16:9 to 4:3" and was rewarded with many results. Too many to list here or to summarize, but I believe that if you research the methods, you should be able to accomplish your goal. One of the summaries I scanned over suggests to set your project to 4:3, import the 16:9 video and decline the dialog box asking to adjust the imported video.